# RN Firebase: Notification methods not triggered; message methods are

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm using React Native Firebase to handle our push notifications. When testing on an iOS device, notifications properly appear when the app is **backgrounded**, so I know the device tokens are working.

However, none of the `Notification` module methods are triggered at any point:

```
// DOES properly fire when message is sent w/o "notification" body (just "data"
this.messageListener = firebase
  .messaging()
  .onMessage(msg => console.log('message', msg));

// doesn't fire when notification is received
this.notificationListener = firebase
  .notifications()
  .onNotification(notification => console.log('on', notification));

// doesn't fire when notification is displayed
this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase
  .notifications()
  .onNotificationDisplayed(notification => console.log('displayed', notification));

// doesn't fire when notification is tapped and app is opened
this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase
  .notifications()
  .onNotificationOpened(notification => console.log('opened', notification));
```

From the RN Firebase docs, everything looks right on our end. Any thoughts?

```
Data payload:

{
  "to": "XXXXXXXXX", // deviceToken
  "notification": {
    "title":"Notification Title",
    "body":"testing testing"
  },
  "data": {
    "user_id": 123,
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried 
firebase
  .notifications()
  .onNotification(notification => console.log('on', notification));
instead of
this.messagingLIstenner = firebase.....

Comment: Did you get this to work in the end? Thanks!